# I don't understand how the Like operator works on non-string data types in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am reading conflicting explanations of the Like operator.

I understand that this is a String operator that compares two string expressions. By that definition, should it not only work on fields with text data types, and not on numeric or date/time fields?

However, when I test the Like operator in a query (in Query Design view), it is able to compare non-string data types. This is confusing.

Can someone please explain if this is a string operator or not?

Comment: Feel free to [edit] and share some example code that uses `Like` the way you're describing, for illustrative purposes - that way readers don't have to make assumptions about the code you're looking at. In the mean time: *implicit type conversions* are likely involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OT here. However, the answer is very simple:

When applying *Like* to a field or variable that is not text, its value will first be *casted* to *localised* text - like what you would see if you from `CStr(SomeValue)`.

Thus, *here* where the decimal separator is *comma*, this will filter out all values for a decimal field:

```
Like "*.*"
```

and this will filter out all integer values:

```
Like "*,*"
```

Comment: Note that the string cast is locale-dependent, thus will make your queries locale-dependent, unless you add a locale-independent decimal separator (e.g. `Like "*" & Format(0, ".") & "*"`) Generally, using `LIKE` with non-string types is nearly always the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA. I thought it was implicit in my answer given the example, but I have emphasized it a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but what does " casted to localised text" and "string cast is locale-dependent" exactly mean?

Comment: It means "have its data type converted" - from, say, Integer to String (if possible). For this, the local settings (formats) for date/time and decimals are used, making such convertions unpredictable. This is why @ErikA mentions, that Like shouldn't be used on fields of any other data type than Text.